# How to create a different workflow depending on result of last run?

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to accomplish the following task using Airflow. I have an `address` and I want to run 3 different tasks `taskA`, `taskB`, `taskC`. Each task returns `True` if the `address` was detected. Store the times when each of the functions detected the `address`.

I want to accomplish the below logic.

1. Run all three tasks to start off with.
2. If any of them return `True`, store the current time.
3. Wait for 1 minute and rerun only the tasks that did not return `True`.
4. If all have returned `True` end the job.

I am not sure how I can accomplish selectively running only those tasks that returned `False` from the last run.

I have so far looked at the `BranchPythonOperator` but I still haven't been able to accomplish the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can get last run status value from airflow db.